# Why is my code only inserting the first element of TIMEPROFILESUBSEGS into the DB?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to loop though JSON and insert data into SQLite DB. But I'm having the issue where only the first element of 'TIMEPROFILESUBSEGS' is being inserted.

After setting a breakpoint on 'timeProfilesList' at the bottom of my code, it appears to contain all the the correct data.  I'm not entirely sure, what the issue is.

Data:

[{"TZID":"00158ffcb97a4c4b9e065546bb33881d","TZITEMID":9,"TZNAME":"Port","COLOR":"#15d8ea","TIMEPROFILESUBSEGS":[{"TZIID":4371,"SERIAL":1,"TIMESLICE":"20:08;20:08;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1"},{"TZIID":4372,"SERIAL":2,"TIMESLICE":"20:06;20:06;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4373,"SERIAL":3,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4374,"SERIAL":4,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4375,"SERIAL":5,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4376,"SERIAL":6,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4377,"SERIAL":7,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4378,"SERIAL":8,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4379,"SERIAL":9,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4380,"SERIAL":10,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4381,"SERIAL":11,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4382,"SERIAL":12,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"}]},{"TZID":"0d06849e96d24ce5babecfa28c9e56be","TZITEMID":10,"TZNAME":"2pm","COLOR":"#000000","TIMEPROFILESUBSEGS":[{"TZIID":4407,"SERIAL":1,"TIMESLICE":"13:00;19:10;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1"},{"TZIID":4408,"SERIAL":2,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4409,"SERIAL":3,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4410,"SERIAL":4,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4411,"SERIAL":5,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4412,"SERIAL":6,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4413,"SERIAL":7,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4414,"SERIAL":8,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4415,"SERIAL":9,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4416,"SERIAL":10,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4417,"SERIAL":11,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"},{"TZIID":4418,"SERIAL":12,"TIMESLICE":"00:00;00:00;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0"}]}

Code:

```
NSArray *timprofiles =[jsonData objectForKey:@"TIMEPROFILE"];


// NSLog(@"DATA LOG %@", timprofiles);

for (NSDictionary * subObject in timprofiles)
{

    NSString *tziid = @"";
    NSString *serial = @"";
    NSString *to_time = @"";
    NSString *from_time = @"";
    NSString *monday = @"";
    NSString *tueday = @"";
    NSString *wednesday = @"";
    NSString *thursday = @"";
    NSString *friday = @"";
    NSString *saturday = @"";
    NSString *sunday = @"";
    NSString *holiday = @"";
    NSString *special_day_one = @"";
    NSString *special_day_two = @"";

    //  NSDictionary *subObject = [timprofiles objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *tzid =[subObject objectForKey:@"TZID"];
    NSString *tzitemid =[subObject objectForKey:@"TZITEMID"];


    NSArray *timeprofiledegments =[subObject objectForKey:@"TIMEPROFILESUBSEGS"];

    NSLog (@"time profile segments %@", timeprofiledegments);




    for (NSDictionary * arryObjects in timeprofiledegments)
    {


        // NSDictionary *arryObjects = [timeprofiledegments objectAtIndex:x];

        tziid =[arryObjects objectForKey:@"TZIID"];
        serial =[arryObjects objectForKey:@"SERIAL"];


        NSString *timeSegList =[arryObjects objectForKey:@"TIMESLICE"];
        NSArray *splitarray =[timeSegList componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];


        for (int j = 0; j < splitarray.count; j++)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
                case 0:
                    from_time =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    to_time =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    monday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tueday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 4:
                    wednesday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 5:
                    thursday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 6:
                    friday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 7:
                    saturday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 8:
                    sunday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 9:
                    holiday =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 10:
                    special_day_one =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                case 11:
                    special_day_two =[splitarray objectAtIndex:j];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }


            [tpOP insertTP:timeProfilesList];

        }


        // NSLog(@"timeprofiledata %@", timeProfilesList);

        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      tziid]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      tzid]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      serial]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      from_time]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      to_time]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      monday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      tueday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      wednesday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      thursday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      friday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      saturday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      sunday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      holiday]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      special_day_one]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      special_day_two]];
        [timeProfilesList addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      tzitemid]];
    }            //end of second for loop



}                //end of forloop
[tpOP insertTP:timeProfilesList];
NSLog (@"done");
[authop addFullSync];
NSLog (@"TIMEPROFILE list array %@", timeProfilesList);
```

SQLite Insert

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *SQLInsert = @"INSERT INTO TIME_PROFILES (TIMEZONE_IID, TIMEZONE_ID, SERIAL, FROM_TIME, TO_TIME ,MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, HOLIDAY, SPECIAL_DAY_ONE, SPECIAL_DAY_TWO, TIMEZONE_ITEM_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQLInsert UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < tpInfo.count; i += 16) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [tpInfo[i] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [tpInfo[i+1] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [tpInfo[i+2] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [tpInfo[i+3] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [tpInfo[i+4] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [tpInfo[i+5] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [tpInfo[i+6] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [tpInfo[i+7] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [tpInfo[i+8] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10, [tpInfo[i+9] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11, [tpInfo[i+10] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 12, [tpInfo[i+11] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [tpInfo[i+12] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 14, [tpInfo[i+13] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 15, [tpInfo[i+14] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 16, [tpInfo[i+15] UTF8String], -1, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
            // NSAssert1(0, @"Cannot Update Table", error);
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Can't prepare: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your timprofiles has 2 objects, then please try to after call

```
  [tpOP insertTP:timeProfilesList]
```

inside outer for loop